# How to concatenate a value to Select-Object's output

Tags: powershell

I have a script which finds snapshots that are older than 3 days and below are my code and output. However I want to add a new column for each VM displaying the actual age of that snapshots, say for example 5 days or 4 days. I have tried getting age by subtracting created date from today's date. But I am not sure how to add it as a column to my output.

I used this to calculate age:

```
$StartDate = Get-Date

$created = Get-VM |
           Get-Snapshot |
           Where {$_.Created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} |
           Select-Object Created

$age = New-Timespan -Start $StartDate -End $created
```

Full code:

```cs
Add-PSSnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core

# HTML formatting
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "BODY{background-color:white;}"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;foreground-color: black;background-color: LightBlue}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 1px;padding: 5px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;foreground-color: black;background-color: white}"
$a = $a + "</style>"

Connect-VIServer -Server ***** -User ****** -Password ******

# Main section of check
Write-Host "Checking VMs for for snapshots"

$date = Get-Date
$datefile = Get-Date -UFormat '%m-%d-%Y-%H%M%S'

$filename = "C:\Temp\snaps_older_than_3\" + $datefile + ".htm"

$created = Get-VM |
           Get-Snapshot |
           Where {$_.Created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} |
           Select-Object Created

$age = New-Timespan -Start $StartDate -End $created

$ss = Get-VM |
      Get-Snapshot |
      Where {$_.Created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} |
      Select-Object vm, name, SizeGB, SizeMB, Created, powerstate + $age |
      ConvertTo-HTML -Head $a -Body "<H2>VM Snapshot Report </H2>"|
      Out-File $filename

Write-Host "   Complete " -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "Your snapshot report has been saved to:" $filename

$SMTPServer = "*******"
$SMTPPort = 25
$username = "vcenter@mmmm.com"

#Define the receiver of the report
$to = "mmmmm@hcl.com"
$subject = "VM Snapshot Report"
$body = "VM Snapshot Report"
$attachment = New-Object Net.Mail.Attachment($filename)
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.Subject = $subject
$message.Body = $body
$message.To.Add($to)
$message.From = $username
$message.Attachments.Add($attachment)
$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $false
$smtp.Send($message)

Write-Host "Mail Sent"
```

Output:

[image]

I want to add a new column named "age".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a calculated property:

```
Get-VM |Select-Object VM,Name,SizeGB,SizeMB,Created,PowerState,@{Name='Age';Expression={New-TimeSpan -Start $StartDate -End $_.Created}}
```

From the [help text for `Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object):

> `-Property`
>   Specifies the properties to select. Wildcards are permitted.
>
> The value of the Property parameter can be a new *calculated property*.
>   To create a calculated property, use a hash table. Valid keys are:
>
> - Name (or Label) `<string>`
> - Expression `<string>` or `<script block>`

Comment: Thank you, I have change my line to                                               
`$ss = Get-VM | Get-Snapshot | Where {$_.Created -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)} | Select-Object vm, name, SizeGB, SizeMB, Created, powerstate,@{Name='Age';Expression={$age=(New-TimeSpan -Start $StartDate -End $_.Created).Minutes}} | ConvertTo-HTML -head $a -body "<H2>VM Snapshot Report </H2>"| Out-File $filename`                                                                                          
But my age column is empty. I have tried with .Days, .Hours and .Minutes, but everything gave empty output.

Comment: Please add this as an edit to your question. Reading code in comments is the suck...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Meanwhile, I have tried that too, but no luck. Are we missing something here.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - Got it, there was a typo in my code, thanks a lot.